# Can't send E-Mails with symfony and swiftmailer using SMTP Server

Tags: symfony, email, smtp, symfony4, swiftmailer

when I try to send an e-Mail I get the error:

> Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be
>   established with host w00d8ef1.kasserver.com [ #0]

.env

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://w00d8ef1.kasserver.com:25?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=myusername&password=mypassword
```

swiftmailer.yaml

```
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

Controller:

```
$message = (new Swift_Message('Test'))
    ->setFrom('info@lama.resper.de')
    ->setTo($user->getEmail())
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            'pdf/usercard.html.twig',
            ['user' => $user]
        ),
        'text/html'
    )
;
$mailer->send($message);
```

Hope someone can help me. The Mailserver is running.

Comment: Is there a firewall on the SMTP server preventing your connection?

Comment: Are you sure that smtp is on port 25? Generally SMTP run on 465 or 587

Comment: @JessGabriel it was port 465, please write it as an answer, then I will accept it.

Comment: Done @Laire. I've added it as response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are using the right port number for smtp? Generally, it runs on 465 or 587. So, try to change the port number in your MAILER_URL env variable.

Answer (score 0):

symfony 4.3

try .env file loks like

MAILER_URL=smtp://YOURDOMAIN.COM:465?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=USEREMAIL@DOMAIN.COM&password=YOURPASSWORD

in config/packages/dev/swiftmailer.yaml (for dev env)
insert:

```
swiftmailer:
transport:        smtp
username:         user@domain.pl
password:         'yourpasswor{$#@'
host:             mail.yourdomain.pl
port:             465
encryption:       ssl
auth-mode:        login
spool: { type: 'memory' }
stream_options:
    ssl:
        allow_self_signed: true
        verify_peer: false
        verify_peer_name: false
```

use

```
php bin/console debug:config swiftmailer
```

to checkout your config

same for production yaml file (but ssl shoud not be self signed)